# Vb.Net crystal report from dataset

Tags: crystal-reports, dataset, report, datasource, fill

I am using Vb.Net 2010 to develop project that has crystal reports. I connect to sqlserver and fill my dataset using the function Adapter.Fill(dataset,"tableName"). My concern now is how can I display the data in my dataset or datatable in crystal report?

Answer (score 0):

here my code using 2 tables authors and titleauthor

```
'Build a SQL statement to query for the authors table 

Dim sqlString As String = "SELECT * FROM authors"

'Retrieve the data using the SQL statement 

adoOleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlString, adoOleDbConnection)

'Build a SQL statement to query for the titleauthor table 

sqlString = "SELECT * FROM titleauthor" 

'Retrieve the data using the SQL statement 

adoOleDbDataAdapter2 = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlString, adoOleDbConnection) 

'Create a instance of a Dataset 

DataSet1 = New DataSet() 

'Fill the dataset with the data with author information 

adoOleDbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet1, "authors") 

'Fill the dataset with the data with titleauthor information. 
'The table name used in the Fill method must be identical to the name 
'of the table in the report. 

adoOleDbDataAdapter2.Fill(DataSet1, "titleauthor") 

'Pass the dataset to the report   YOU NEED THIS

Dim crReportDocument As New CrystalReport1()


crReportDocument.Database.Tables(0).SetDataSource(DataSet1) 

'View the report 

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crReportDocument
```

Remember you need to import

Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine 
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared

Answer (score 0):

You can create dataset in project
right click project>add new item> select Data > select dataset. specify the name of dataset for eg: dsTest.xsd.
double click and it'll all us to create table and columns within that. the name of table has to match the tablename you specify in adapter.fill statement.
column name and their datatype has to match as the result of adapter.fill statement.

now you can use search for this dataset in database expert of crystal report.
database expert > project data > ado.net datasets > dstest.xsd

add the columns you need to design report.