# How to populate sql query result in crystal report with vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am new to work with vb.net and crystal report I searched many links while failed to populate or load SQL query result on crystal report?

here is the code to load query result on grid-view

```
 Dim cc As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(" Server=(localdb)\Projects;Database=question;Uid=sa;Pwd=12345;")
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT  * FROM tencmpC1 where qnumber in 1,2,3 ", cc)
             Dim adp, As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        cmd.Connection.Open()Dim ds As DataTable = New DataTable
           adp.Fill(ds)
        grid.ItemsSource = ds.DefaultView
        cmd.Connection.Dispose()
```

But what i did with grid-view same that i want with crystal report ?

Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT  * FROM tencmpC1 where qnumber in 1,2,3 ", cc)

may be number changed every time 1,2,3 or 4,85,9 or 54,96,400 .

here I only need guidance on loading SQL query result on crystal report?

thanks in advance.

sorry if its hard to understand I try my level best to express my self what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do this :

1. **Crystal Report Parameters** : User can manually pass the parameters to the crystal report at runtime. Using this `Parameters`, you can pass the desired values to the Crystal Reports. In your example, to SQL Query.
2. Create a query which accepts data as parameter. And while loading the Crystal Report, Fill data Adapter with that query which will ultimately fill the Crystal Report according to the query.

Comment: will you give me a piece of code who to do this task while CReport installed and sql code above declared ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829545/vb-net-crystal-report-from-dataset
i used code from above link but not working

Comment: Ok. which method you are gonna use ?

Comment: 2nd one i think better in my case is that similar like above method with grid view?

Comment: i try this one code but found error "Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX)

            cmd.Connection.Open()
            Dim adp As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

            Dim hdt As New DataSet()
            adp.Fill(hdt, "tencmpC1")


            Dim crReportDocument As New CrystalReport1()


            crReportDocument.Database.Tables("Emcq").SetDataSource(hdt)

            'View the report 

            '  CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crReportDocument
            cr2.ViewerCore.ReportSource = crReportDocument
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: Create a Report -> Create a Form with `CrystalReportViewer` -> If you have a `DataSource`, drag the required table to form. This will create a Grid and BindingNavigator. Delete all controls except `CrystalReportViewer`. This method is used to create a Fill method and DataSet objects. -> On required event, use `Fill` method for Dragged `TableAdapter` -> Create a Report object and Set `SetDataSource` property to Dragged `Dataset` for that object. -> Now pass this Report object to `CrystalReportViewer`

Feel free to ask if you stuck..

Comment: sorry what mean by this " If you have a DataSource, drag the required table to form. This will create a Grid and BindingNavigator." may be you did not understand my point i want to dynamically populate CR with parametrized query every time may be table or columns will be changed like wise we do with grid view?

Comment: Well, skip that step and try to fill the `TableAdapter` with your parameterized  query. That should work too